# MySQL non-aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I am new to SQL and my question is, "What are three non-aggregated MySQL functions"? I know that some aggregated functions in SQL is: SUM(), COUNT() and AVG(). But what are some non-aggregated functions (as my question stands)?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html

Comment: all aggregate functions are the ones you can find here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html, and all other functions that are not aggregate are non-aggregated :) but they are not usually called this way. maybe you are asking about non aggregated columns in MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the standard MYSQL doesnt have anything called non-aggregate functions. As you have already pointed that in MySQL we have aggregate functions including AVG, COUNT, SUM, MAX and MIN. But we dont have any non-aggregate functions as such.

However there are [Mathematical Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html) and [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) in MySql which you can look for. As pointed correct by  a_horse_with_no_name in comments the functions which are defined in the link are rather scalar functions. They are not aggregate functions so you can call them non aggregate function but if you search as non aggregate functions in Mysql I am not very sure you will find something.

Comment: So what about these: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html or these: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html None of them are aggregate functions (or to the other way round: those are non-aggregate functions, sometimes also called scalar functions)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:- Yes I have added them too in my answer. But I think there is no terminology called non aggregate function in Mysql(Or I am missing something?)

Comment: In general those are refered to as "scalar functions" - but I don't see a reason why they couldn't be called "non-aggregate" functions (as the opposite to "aggregate")

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:- Yes you are quite correct(as always.) Tried to update my answer accordingly! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of such a term. However, using my imagination, I guess they'res all functions that are not aggregated :)

There are plenty of them. You have [date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html), [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html), etc.

Just to give the 3 examples I'd say: MONTH(), COALESCE(), FIELD()